# Вызов внешней программы

Tags: c++, gpss

В программе нужно вызвать внешнюю, в частности, среду моделирования `GPSS World` и передать туда текст описания. Может кто знает, есть ли у нее параметры вызова. Или как это еще можно сделать? Чтобы она открылась - и текст описания уже был в ней. Мое мнение: если есть параметры запуска, то `system("gpssw.exe ...")` или чрерз `ShellExecute(...)`.

Comment: Так вы экспериментально проверье - в консоли через cmd позапускайте с какими-нибудь опциями и посмотрите, что она скажет в консоль. Если она поддерживает какие-то консольные параметры, то она ругнётся на то, что вы ей предложите. Попробуйте подсунуть ей путь к файлу.. если повезёт, то она воспримет его как файл, из которого надо прочесть это самое описание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Из [руководства](http://www.kfmesi.ru/bibl/ymk/pi/uchmat/imep/gpss/imep_2.doc):*

> A new Batch Mode of operation can be
> used to run simulations in the
> background. If you specify a Model
> File or a Simulation File on the DOS
> command line followed by the word
> "BATCH", GPSS World will run in a
> minimized window. It first opens the
> file and then passes it a Create
> Command (if a Model Object) or a
> CONTINUE Command (if a Simulation
> Object). In the former case, you would
> normally append the desired run
> control Commands in the Model itself.
> You can use the new EXIT 1 Command (or
> Exit(1) Library Procedure) to shut
> down the resulting Session by itself,
> automatically saving all the newly
> created or modified Objects. EXIT is
> discussed in Chapter 6.